# How to keep my variable updated using AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, alpine.js

First post here,
I'm currently working on a web project where I'm using Alpine.js for some dynamic functionality. In my project, I have a shopping cart feature, and I want to display the total price of items in the cart on my webpage.

Here's a simplified version of my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Meta tags and CSS imports -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>YMRESTKOMBYEN</title>
  <!-- Customized Tailwind CSS and Alpine.js -->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    /* Custom color variables */
    :root {
      --color-bg: #422931;
      --color-text: #ffffff;
      --color-accent: #09da6b;
    }

    body {
      background-color: var(--color-bg);
    }

    .text-primary {
      color: var(--color-text);
    }

    .btn-primary {
      background-color: var(--color-accent);
      color: var(--color-text);
    }
  </style>
  <!-- Alpine.js script import -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="px-3 font-sans leading-normal tracking-normal" x-data="loadMotorcycles()" x-data="{totalCart:0">
  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="bg-gray-900 text-white py-6">
    <!-- ... (header code) ... -->
  </header>

  <!-- Main content container -->
  <div class="container pt-8 mx-auto" x-cloak>
    <!-- Search input -->
    <input x-ref="searchField" x-model="search" placeholder="Rechercher par marque ou modèle..." type="search"
      class="block w-full bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-900 focus:shadow text-white font-bold rounded-lg px-4 py-3 text-primary">

    <!-- Sorting dropdown -->
    <div class="mt-4">
      <label class="block text-gray-100 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Trier par :</label>
      <select x-model="sortOption"
        class="block w-full bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-900 focus:shadow text-white font-bold rounded-lg px-4 py-3 text-primary">
        <!-- ... (sorting options) ... -->
      </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Motorcycle list -->
    <div class="mt-4 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
      <template x-for="moto in sortedMotorcycles" :key="moto.id">
        <div
          class="flex items-center shadow hover:bg-gray-700 hover:shadow-lg hover:rounded transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105 p-3 bg-gray-800"
          @click="totalCart += moto.prix">
          <!-- ... (motorcycle details) ... -->
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript section -->
  <script>
    // Sample motorcycle data
    var sourceData = [
      // ... (motorcycle json format data) ...
    ];

    // Function to load and manipulate motorcycle data
    function loadMotorcycles() {
      return {
        search: '',
        sortOption: 'default',
        myForData: sourceData,
        get sortedMotorcycles() {
          // ... (sorting and filtering logic) ...
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I realized that having both the variable totalCart and the function loadMotorcycles as x-datas inside the body wasn't possible,
I'm new to AlpineJS and I've tried the documentation, but I really don't know how to grasp it.

I'd love to have guidance on how to proceed, and feel free to ask any question.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the *totalCart* variable to the main x-data JSON:

```js
function loadMotorcycles() {

    return {

        totalCart:0,

        search: '',
        sortOption: 'default',
    
        // .....

   }
}
```

and possibly you can rename *loadMotorcycles()* with a more generic name.

You can also split the logic into multiple Alpine.js components each with their own *x-data*.
A child component can access the parent's data, otherwise components can interact with each other using [custom events](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/events#dispatching-custom-events)

I also suggest you to use the version 3 of Alpine.js: [here](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation) some details.